# Is it possible to change settings for vrapper as you do for .vim?

Tags: eclipse, vim, plugins

Is it possible to change settings for [Vrapper](http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/home/) as you can do for .vim (e.g., add key mappings, change editor settings, etc.)?

Comment: Is Vrapper's documentation so poor that you could not find out this trivial thing, or didn't you look [hard enough]?!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, vrapper supports mappings and many configurations including `expandtab`, `shiftwidth`, `softtabstop`, `tabstop`, `hlsearch` as the official documentation says you just have to create a `~/.vrapperrc` or `_vrapperrc` file: http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/documentation/?page=6

Comment: Where can I set the path for .vrapperrc in Windows?

Comment: It's something like C:\Users\Nexus2020\.vrapperrc in your case

Comment: Just wanted to clarify on one pain point in configuring vrapper for windows: https://github.com/vrapper/vrapper/issues/52
Save vrapper file as 'all type'. It should not be saved as a text document. This is one of the main reasons that despite creating .vrapperrc it does not get loaded in eclipse.